# Change civicrm combobox value from the code

Tags: wordpress, civimember

I want to know how to change the value of those awesome civicrm comboboxes from the code (i have google address search, I need to change the country), see the screenshot. 
jQuery("#country-1").val(val); document.getElementById('country-1').value = val; don't work
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The widget is [select2 3.5](http://select2.github.io/select2/). But you don't need to interact with it directly. Find a selector for the underlying `<select>` element in the dom, set it's value, and then fire the change event. E.g.

```
CRM.$(function($) {
  $("#country-1").val(val).change()
});
```

Note that you should use CiviCRM's copy of jQuery and not the WP copy. So the above code uses `CRM.$` instead of `jQuery`. Using the wrong copy of jQuery would make things weird as change events would appear to have no effect, etc.